# Use wget to get a csv

Tags: ubuntu, wget

I am using Ubuntu and have a [known URL](http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/HOU/2011/7/1/CustomHistory.html?dayend=26&monthend=10&yearend=2012&format=1) which I need to download/save as a CSV. The URL is based on a parameter and changes often for a project, so I want to write a script which does the download, so that I don't have to manually save it every single time.

I was trying to use wget to get the file, but the website displays the contents as CSV, while the file itself is an HTML. How can I save the content of the page as a pure csv?

```
wget -O my.csv [url]
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only HTML in the file is `<br />` at the end of each line. To remove it, you can just

```
wget -O- "$URL" | sed 's#<br />$##' > my.csv
```

Comment: If you see the source in chrome or any browser, then you are right. The file I am getting after the wget command is a full blown html :)

Comment: I wonder why am I getting a weird output with the same code then..With your code I am getting a file of 0 bytes. Can I know which OS are you using?

Comment: I had forgotten the inverted commas for the URL. It works. Thanks!